# Popup menu in a view for an icon ..?

Tags: android, xml, popup

what is the best way to get that  kind of popup menu (src youtube)? (was trying with spinner but can not find a command where only icon-three dots will be shown before expending without any text in given picture[image]- )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button with a popup window could be a solution for you. Do you need an example?

Comment: great!:)- I will google it up and try it on my own - ty:)